# react-native-document-picker: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNDocumentPicker.pick')

Tags: typescript, react-native, typeerror

I try to use DocumentPicker.pick for file picking, but it keeps throwing error ***"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNDocumentPicker.pick')"***. I traces down this error, and it leads to **"node_modules/react-native-document-picker/src/index.tsx"** [THIS FILE](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/blob/master/src/index.tsx)

```js
/// Line 1
import { Platform, NativeModules, ModalPropsIOS } from 'react-native'
/// Line 27
const RNDocumentPicker: DocumentPickerType = NativeModules.RNDocumentPicker
```

The NativeModules seems not to exist (is blank object {} ), even when I change import line, can import NativeModules and log it out, it does not contain RNDocumentPicker.

Therefore, NativeModules.RNDocumentPicker is null, and RNDocumentPicker is NULL  !?

#### Reproducible sample code

```js
import DocumentPicker from "react-native-document-picker";
async uploadAttachFiles() {
      try {
          var pickerResult = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        })
        console.log(" ~ file: ChatInputBar.js:188 ~ ChatInputBar ~ uploadAttachFiles ~ pickerResult:", pickerResult)
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(" ~ file: ChatInputBar.js:190 ~ ChatInputBar ~ uploadAttachFiles ~ e:", e)
      }
  }
```

*I catch the error and log it there: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNDocumentPicker.pick')*

#### Steps to reproduce

1. npm i react-native-document-picker --save --force
2. npx react-native start
3. npx react-native run-android

Describe what you expected to happen:

1. Function DocumentPicker.pick works fine, shoud pop-up a file picker for android, ios
2. Be able to pick file and upload it to server

#### What I have already done

1. Try npx react-native link, npx react-native-asset for linking
2. Try npm install serveral time
3. Grant access for android (in "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
4. Change "android/settings.gradle" and "android/app/build.gradle" (according to older version of this library)
5. Try older version of this library (3.x.x, 2.x.x), still have this problem
6. Rebuild android by deleting app in android simulator and running "npx react-native run-android" again and again
7. Run './gradle clean' in android

#### Environment info

`npx react-native info` output:

```bash
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Linux 5.15 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400 CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 7.14 GB / 15.45 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /usr/bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.5.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.18 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.18 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: ^0.71.7 => 0.63.4 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

library version: 8.2.0

iOS / Android version: unknown

I ran on Android simulator (of Android Studio)

Comment: Can you share the project in github?